# How to Fix a Hole in your Waterproof pool?

Tags: substitute-tool, water, summer

During the summer you always face the issue of getting the pool ready, whether this pool is large or small or dirty or rather clean. One of the worst instances is when the pool has a hole in it. And while you can spend money and time on pool fixing equipment or stuff made specifically for the job, you can use a substitute if you know one. My question is what is a good substitute for waterproofing a hole in a pool without buying some product?

**Things that I have used:**

- Duct Tape. This worked pretty good, but eventually got dirty and started to peel.
- Glue. This worked for about a day or 2, but depending on the hole size this can be a pretty hard task.
- Waterproof materials taped up or glued on. This worked for a little longer than the tape and glue, but again it was less than 2 weeks.

*Note: Keep in mind that I use the pool pretty frequent, so anything I use should be able to hold up to that standard.*

Answer (score 3):

Most people have bikes and should thus have a bike tube repair kit. Follow the instructions and you can fix the hole.

Basic instructions are these, but if the kit has instructions you should follow those.

1. Take some sandpaper or something else to the area around the hole, scuff the surface to ensure proper glue adhesion.
2. Put glue on both the hole and the patch, you can use a piece of bike tubing as a patch, but make sure to scuff it if you do. Let the glue sit for a couple of minutes until it becomes tacky.
3. Press both pieces together for a few minutes to ensure good adhesion.

Answer (score 1):

***What you can do is:***

- Use a Waterproof Tarp. Tarps can be used to line the pool so that the water does not flow out the hole. In many cases I have used the tarp to line a friends truck, hole or even a large container. This effectively makes anything a pool. Shower curtains(waterproof), tablecloths(waterproof ones) or even waterproof bed sheets and mattress covers can be used. Plus, if you dig a pool hole your pool can be as big as you like it to be.

This is a [interesting idea,](http://diycozyhome.com/how-to-build-a-hay-bale-swimming-pool/) and can be used with logs, or other structures if you dont have enough hay.